# Cannot change visibility of Excel range name to false

Tags: excel, office-js

Using script lab.

I am trying to work with Excel range names. Most of this I got working, but there is one thing that I cannot get to work: set visibility of a name to false:

```
let namedItem = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("test");
namedItem.visible = false;
await context.sync();
```

What gives???

##EDIT: If the name is already hidden, I can set the visible property to true and it indeed makes that name visible again. Why can’t I do the other way around?
END OF EDIT##

##EDIT
Another oddity is that you can hide a name immediately after creating it:

```
namedItem = context.workbook.names.add(nameName, refersTo);
await context.sync();
if (!namedItem.isNullObject) {
  namedItem.visible = $("#nameVisible").prop("checked");
  await context.sync();
  }
```

So why can't I do that on a subsequent edit?

END OF EDIT##

Answer (score 0):

Use [setVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.nameditem?view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-nameditem-setvisible-member(1)) instead of `visible`.

```
let namedItem = context.workbook.names.getItemOrNullObject("test");
let range = namedItem.getRange();
range.setVisible(false);
await context.sync();
```

Comment: I'm not intending to hide the range, but I want to hide the name, so it doesn't show in name manager.

Comment: I tried setVisible, but it generates an error.