# Trying to change visible property of NamedItem

Tags: office-js

Follow-up to [Cannot change visibility of Excel range name to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571887/cannot-change-visibility-of-excel-range-name-to-false)

I'm trying to update properties of an existing range name in Excel using office-js in Script lab.

Why doesn't this code work?

I'm trying to change the visible property of a name, but this snippet does not change the visible property, only the formula:

```
async function AddEditName() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let wb = context.workbook;
    let refersTo: string = $("#cellSelector")
      .val()
      .toString();
    let nameName: string = $("#rangeName")
      .val()
      .toString();
    let sheetName: string = $("#nameScope option:selected")
      .val()
      .toString();
    let namedItem;

    if (sheetName == "workbook") {
      namedItem = wb.names.getItemOrNullObject(nameName);
    } else {
      namedItem = wb.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).names.getItemOrNullObject(nameName);
    }
    namedItem.load();
    await context.sync();
    if (namedItem.isNullObject) {
      //name does not exist, add
      if (nameName.length > 0 && refersTo.length > 0) {
        if (sheetName == "workbook") {
          namedItem = wb.names.add(nameName, refersTo);
        } else {
          namedItem = wb.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).names.add(nameName, refersTo);
        }
        await context.sync();
        if (!namedItem.isNullObject) {
          namedItem.visible = $("#nameVisible").prop("checked");
          await context.sync();
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Please provide both a name and a formula");
      }
    } else {
      namedItem.formula = refersTo;
      namedItem.visible = $("#nameVisible").prop("checked");
      await context.sync();
    }
    await displayNamesList();
  });
}
```

###EDITED: Placed full AddEditName function###

Comment: Provide the entire `Excel.run` method.

Comment: Will do that tomorrow, thanks

Comment: I've edited the question and inserted the entire function

Comment: You're making it too hard to try and reproduce. You've left out the `displayNamesList` and you're forcing people to create a task pane UI that matches  yours. Please create the simplest possible version that shows the problem. Also, if I replace `namedItem.visible = $("#nameVisible").prop("checked");` with `namedItem.visible = true;` or `namedItem.visible = false;`, it seems to work. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Not sure what to say, after reloading the script lab item from the gist it now works. No changes made to the above code. Thanks for looking into this, @RickKirkham